# Is there any solution to combine two or more docx files?

Tags: node.js, docx

Is there any solution about merging two or more docx files into one by appending one to another?

I'll use it in my JavaScript Nodejs application. I've tried `docx-merger` module, but it has so much errors. It can be an exe file.

Thanks

Comment: How about opening the files separately and the appending contents of one onto another? Will that work properly with docx format?

Comment: It's an automation system, so it should be automatic